# Issue with interactive plot on matplotlib within jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have this issue after selecting the zoom button on the interactive toolbar beneath the plot. When I click to draw a rectangle (for zooming in to), black lines appears. This only happens in the bottom and right-most side of the plot.

I am using Python 3.6.4 and the following packages:

- matplotlib (2.1.2)
- jupyter (1.0.0)

Code to reproduce issue (within jupyter notebook):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
plt.plot(random(100), random(100), '.')
```

[image]

Comment: With the same versions I cannot reproduce your issue, have you tried restarting the kernel?

Comment: Yes, I did restart the kernel and deactivate/activate the virtual environment.